# When typing in any word plus a colon, SSMS to recognizes it as valid and is able to run it. Why?

Tags: sql, ssms

Normally when I come across something new I like to take some time learn about it. But I've been searching StackOverflow and Google and I can't find anything.

For example:

```
blahblah:
```

will turn blue in SSMS and, if executed, return "Command(s) completed successfully."

I've searched and searched and I can't seem to find anything about it.  What feature does it think I am trying running here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Labels used with [GOTO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180188.aspx)

```
print 1
goto blahblah
print 2
blahblah:
print 3
```

---

```
1
3
```

Comment: ha! Completely forgot about the gotos.  Thank you, kind sir.  I guess it was hard to find because nobody searches for the tag without the goto.

Comment: Will do! I have to wait 6 minutes ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is a label which you can use GOTO with:

Syntax:

```
label:   
...sql...
GOTO label
```

See more at [GOTO (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180188.aspx)